# React Data being lost on page refresh arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a dynamic react component that will show company profiles based on the route ID. I'm currently using sample data from a data.js file which just stores the data.

**Problem**
When I click through to the dynamic page, all the data loads the first time. Then, when I refresh, I'm thrown an error: 'cannot read property name of undefined', so I assume the data isn't reloading, but I'm not sure how to make the data stay on page reload. Code below:

**DynamicPage.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Overview } from './maincomp/components'
import data from '../UserList/data'

  const company = () => {
     if(users !== undefined){
       users.find((row) => {
       return match.params.id == row.id
      })?.name
   } else { return null }

  return(
    <div>
      {company.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchCompany
```

**data.js**

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v1';

export default [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'exampleone',
    investors: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    website: "https://exampleone.com",
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'exampletwo',
    investors: ['n', 'm', 'l'],
    website: "https://exampletwo.com",
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'examplethree',
    investors: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    website: "https://examplethree.com",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to call from the state, so, if you create the state by useState, that's mean you create a variable with it.
back to old code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Overview } from './maincomp/components'
import data from '../UserList/data'

const SearchCompany = ({match}) => {

  const [users] = useState(data);

  const company = () => {
    return (
     users.find((row) =>match.params.id === row.id)?.name )
   }

  return(
    <div>
      {company}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchCompany
```

**Note removed data.js and added to question

Comment: Thanks Hakim. I've updated my code above to reflect your answer, but am still getting an error "Nothing was returned from the render", do you know why that is?

Comment: No, it shows "Nothing was returned from the render"

Comment: try to remove '''else {return null}'''

Comment: THanks Hakim! I'm now getting a parsing error "unexpected token .?"

Comment: ?.name not .?name

Comment: Yes that then threw another error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" - sorry for all the questions!

Comment: Thanks so much Hakim, that makes sense. It loads but doesn't load the data from the imported data file. EG when I type {company.name}, it prints out "company", instead of that company's name.

Comment: I added data.js for contex on the data I want to render

Comment: in this code, you have add ?.name in company.. so, you don't need to return name again in return,, so just return ( <div>{company}</div>) this should be automatically call the company name

Comment: Thanks - it still just shows up as "company" - I want to be able to call all data for each entry (i.e. name, investors, website) on the dynamic page, but I still just get company for name when I edit it the way you mention

Comment: ooh i see, so the point, you want this to show all of the data

Comment: Yes, do you know How I can do that?

Comment: Thanks! In the answer above or?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Overview } from './maincomp/components'
import data from '../UserList/data'

const SearchCompany = ({match}) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(data);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (users) {
      users.find(row => {
        if (match.params.id === row.id) {
          setName(() => row.name);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [match, users]);

  return(
    <div>
      {company.name}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchCompany
```

Comment: Thanks Manan, but when I do this I get the same error: it works when I click it, but not when I refresh it. When I refresh I get 'cannot read property name of undefined', and I want it to stay on refresh.

Comment: Do you mind creating a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Thanks Manan, trying to make a sandbox but finding it hard to create as project is complex so lots of stuff needed, the only issue I'm having is that when I refresh the page, I can no longer read the data that was sent to it.

Comment: I used the code you posted and created [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-goodall-wxnlh) sandbox. Please check it out and let me know if it'll solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Manan! I don't think it solves my issue though. If I take your example, what I want is to go to "page/:id" and show the data relevant to that ID. Right now, I'm doing that, but when I refresh, it dissappears.

Comment: All I can say from the info you provided is you'll have to do some sort of `useEffect` call to get your desired results

Comment: Thanks Manan! WIll try to implement and post solution when done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210166/discussion-between-manan-joshi-and-luke-byrne).

Answer (score 1):

```
if you want to call all data, and the id is equal with someId, <br/>
you must to loop it first. <br/>

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Overview } from './maincomp/components'
import data from '../UserList/data'
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom' //if use this to call params

  const theData = data
  const id = useParams()

  const company = () => {
   return (
    theData.map(item =>
     <div>
       Id: {item.find(_item => _item.id === id)?.id}
       Name: {item.find(_item => _item.id === id)?.name}
       Websites: {item.find(_item => _item.id === id)?.website}
     </div>
    ))
   }

//use this
const company2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    id: {theData.find(item => item.id === id)?.id}
    Name: {theData.find(item => item.id === id)?.name}
    Website: {theData.find(item => item.id === id)?.website}
    Investors: {theData.find(item => item.id === id)?.investors.map(__item => <div>{__item}</div> ) }
    </div>
  )
}

  return(
    <div>
      {company()}
      {company2()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchCompany

data.js
export default [
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'exampleone',
    investors: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    website: "https://exampleone.com",
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'exampletwo',
    investors: ['n', 'm', 'l'],
    website: "https://exampletwo.com",
  },
  {
    id: uuid(),
    name: 'examplethree',
    investors: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    website: "https://examplethree.com",
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks again Hakim, but when I call company, it then prints out the entire dataset. I only want to print the relevant row of data.

Comment: See data.js, so for example on "page/:id", I want to show the name, investors and website for that companies ID. On refresh, I want it to stay there

Comment: ooh i see, so add find in there

Comment: It comes up item.find is not a function now.

Comment: my fault
not item.find
but
{theData.find(_item => _item.id === id)?.id}

Comment: Thanks. That just shows up blank, so I get when I call company() I get ID: Name: Websites 3 times as it still calls everything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210168/discussion-between-luke-byrne-and-hakim).

Comment: Thanks Hakim, I opened a chat to discuss there.

Comment: No, it still shows up just id: name: website: investors, no data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useMemo` like so:

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

const company = useMemo(() => users.find((row) => {
    return match.params.id == row.id
  }), [users]);
```

Comment: Thanks Fayeed. When I do this, I get the same error. Do you know why?

Comment: 'cannot read property name of undefined' - same as with my code above.